# [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined" vue test util

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to mock an `axios` put request in `nuxt.js` like this:

The component method(Composition API approach):

```js
const doSomething = async (): Promise<void> => {
  const token = $cookies.get("token");
  const headers = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  };
  try {
    const response = await $axios.$put(
      `/api/v1/post/${data.value.id}/update`,
      {
        status: "ok",
      },
      { headers }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

and test file:

```js
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import axios from "axios";
import MyComponent from "~/components/MyComponent/index.vue";

const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>
const mockRes = { code: 200 };

jest.mock("axios", () => ({
  put: jest.fn(() => {
    mockRes;
  }),
}));
describe("MyComponent.vue", () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent);
  test("should do something", async () => {
    await wrapper.find('[data-test="do-something"]').trigger("click");
  });
});
```

as you can see everything looks fine, but I get some error in the console when I run tests
for instance, I get this error for this moment:

`[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"`

I think its for $cookies.get

but why did this happen? and how can I fix it?

Comment: $cookies is not defined, you should mock it

Comment: @jeremycastelli  I've added like this: `mocks:{$cookies:{}}` in shallowMount option for mocking that but it didn't work.
like here 
https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/using-with-vue-router.html#mocking-route-and-router

Comment: I'm not that an expert in jest to help you more. Just some thoughts : Why the dollar sign for $cookies and $axios ? do you import them in your component or they are injected at the app level in every components. If so, then this is the vue instance you have to mock

Comment: @jeremycastelli $axios is by default located in `useContext()` function in `@nuxtjs/nuxt-composition-api` and also in nuxt itself, and as probably  you know, you can access `$axios`, with `this.$axios` if  you'll install it, for `$cookies` I've added to `$cookies`  to `useContext()` too, with creating a `config.d.ts` in the root of the project and added like this `declare module '*.vue' {
  import $cookies from 'cookie-universal-nuxt'
  export default $cookies
}`

Comment: @jeremycastelli so yes I think they are top-level except `$cookies` which I added like above who I explain it, so how can I mock Vue instance?

would you please give me some resources or code,  I'll appreciate that

Comment: Sorry as I said, I can't help you much more with this, I'm not good enough in jest.

Comment: can we see the `.vue` component ?

Comment: @jeremycastelli no problem bro, thanks for your time

Comment: @AdriHM You can consider that function as the script of the file, and a button with the attribute of `data-test="do-something` for triggering that function, anyway it throws an error

Comment: I think you have to mock $cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock `$cookies` like this:

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, {
    mocks: {
      $cookies: {
         get: jest.fn()
      }    
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it still gives me the same error

Comment: you have to mock it like you did with axios so

Comment: Thakns It's work with `mocks` instead of `$mocks`

Comment: oh yeah sorry, well done buddy